# Import information from file to mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

How can i import information from a file (like below) to my mysql database by a php file?

I was thinking by open a file, insert a row into a variabele and check every line for an = mark and insert the information into array's by checking the tag bevore the =.

Is this the right way or are there better ways.

Example file:

```
# Disc length: 926 seconds
# Revision: 0
# Processed by: cddbd v1.5PL3 Copyright (c) Steve Scherf et al.
# Submitted via: audiograbber 1.83.01

DISCID=00039c14
DTITLE=3M Littmann Stethoscope Edition / 20 Beispiele zur Herz- und Lungenausku
DTITLE=ltation
DYEAR=1997
DGENRE=Medizin
TTITLE0=Normale Herztöne
TTITLE1=Dritter Herzton (physiologisch)
TTITLE2=Vierter Herzton
TTITLE3=Aortenklappenstenose
TTITLE4=Mitralklappeninsuffizienz
TTITLE5=Mittelsystolischer Klick
TTITLE6=Ventrikelseptum-Defekt
TTITLE7=Atriumseptum-Defekt
TTITLE8=Mitralklappenstenose
TTITLE9=Aortenklappeninsuffizienz
TTITLE10=normales tracheales Atemgeräusch
TTITLE11=normales vesikuläres Atemgeräusch
TTITLE12=feine Krepitation mit leichter bronchialer Atmung
TTITLE13=rauhe Krepitation
TTITLE14=bronchiale Atmung
TTITLE15=Stridor beim Einatmen
TTITLE16=Rhonchus
TTITLE17=pfeifender Rhonchus (Keuchatmen)
TTITLE18=feine Krepitation (Knisterrasseln)
TTITLE19=pleurales Reibungsgeräusch
EXTD=
EXTT0=
EXTT1=
EXTT2=
EXTT3=
EXTT4=
EXTT5=
EXTT6=
EXTT7=
EXTT8=
EXTT9=
EXTT10=
EXTT11=
EXTT12=
EXTT13=
EXTT14=
EXTT15=
EXTT16=
EXTT17=
EXTT18=
EXTT19=
PLAYORDER=
```

Comment: The right way is to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: Show the code you wrote so far in order to get advice. Your explanation is not clear so it's difficult to say if your approach is good.

Comment: check this https://github.com/austinhyde/IniParser/blob/master/src/IniParser.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$settingArray = array();
$text = file('file.txt');
foreach($text as $line){
    $line = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $line);
    if(substr($line, 0, 1) != '#' && !empty($line)){
        $key = substr($line, 0, strpos($line, "="));
        $value = substr($line, strpos($line, "=") + 1);
        $value = substr($value, 0, strpos($value, "#") != 0 ? strpos($value, "#") : strlen($value)); //removes everything behind a # sign

        $settingArray[$key] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($settingArray);
/*this will print:
array (size=46)
  'DISCID' => string '00039c14' (length=8)
  'DTITLE' => string 'ltation' (length=7)
  'DYEAR' => string '1997' (length=4)
  'DGENRE' => string 'Medizin' (length=7)
  'TTITLE0' => string 'Normale Herztöne ' (length=17)
  'TTITLE1' => string 'Dritter Herzton (physiologisch)' (length=31)
  'TTITLE2' => string 'Vierter Herzton' (length=15)
  'TTITLE3' => string 'Aortenklappenstenose' (length=20)
  'TTITLE4' => string 'Mitralklappeninsuffizienz' (length=25)
  'TTITLE5' => string 'Mittelsystolischer Klick' (length=24)
  'TTITLE6' => string 'Ventrikelseptum-Defekt' (length=22)
  'TTITLE7' => string 'Atriumseptum-Defekt' (length=19)
  'TTITLE8' => string 'Mitralklappenstenose' (length=20)
  'TTITLE9' => string 'Aortenklappeninsuffizienz' (length=25)
  'TTITLE10' => string 'normales tracheales Atemgeräusch' (length=32)
  'TTITLE11' => string 'normales vesikuläres Atemgeräusch' (length=33)
  'TTITLE12' => string 'feine Krepitation mit leichter bronchialer Atmung' (length=49)
  'TTITLE13' => string 'rauhe Krepitation' (length=17)
  'TTITLE14' => string 'bronchiale Atmung' (length=17)
  'TTITLE15' => string 'Stridor beim Einatmen' (length=21)
  'TTITLE16' => string 'Rhonchus' (length=8)
  'TTITLE17' => string 'pfeifender Rhonchus (Keuchatmen)' (length=32)
  'TTITLE18' => string 'feine Krepitation (Knisterrasseln)' (length=34)
  'TTITLE19' => string 'pleurales Reibungsgeräusch' (length=26)
  'EXTD' => boolean false
  'EXTT0' => boolean false
  'EXTT1' => boolean false
  'EXTT2' => boolean false
  'EXTT3' => boolean false
  'EXTT4' => boolean false
  'EXTT5' => boolean false
  'EXTT6' => boolean false
  'EXTT7' => boolean false
  'EXTT8' => boolean false
  'EXTT9' => boolean false
  'EXTT10' => boolean false
  'EXTT11' => boolean false
  'EXTT12' => boolean false
  'EXTT13' => boolean false
  'EXTT14' => boolean false
  'EXTT15' => boolean false
  'EXTT16' => boolean false
  'EXTT17' => boolean false
  'EXTT18' => boolean false
  'EXTT19' => boolean false
  'PLAYORDER' => boolean false*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simple ignore lines starting with # and then in all other lines (not-empty) find first occurrence of `=` sign and using susbtr (or mb_substr) you will get columns and columns values.

**EDIT**

Someone suggest it's INI file however in fact it isn't so you cannot use `parse_ini_file` function.  First thing is that comments here start with '#` what would generate Deprecated warning (ini PHP 5.5.12) and in addition because no quotes were used you will get warning :

```
Warning: syntax error, unexpected '(' in test.ini on line 12
```

and this function will return `false`

**EDIT2**

I would do it this way:

```
<?php

$data = array();
$lines = file('test.ini');

mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

foreach($lines as $line){
    $line = trim($line);
    if ($line == '' || mb_substr($line,0,1) == '#') {
        continue;
    }

    $pos = mb_strpos($line, '=');

    if ($pos == false)  {   // == not ===
        continue;    
    }


  $data[mb_substr($line,0,$pos)] = mb_substr($line, $pos + 1);

}

var_dump($data);
```

You need to trim each line first and remove empty lines and lines starting with `#` as I said before, then you check for occurrence of `=`. If it's not found or at 0 position simple you need to ignore this line, all other lines are placed into `$data` array

Comment: It's an INI file, so parsing it manually is not the best of ideas imo.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting guys. What's wrong with this answer?